# The "is" in JUnit 4 assertions

Tags: java, junit, coding-style, junit4, assertions

Is there any semantic difference between writing

```
assertThat(object1, is(equalTo(object2)));
```

and writing

```
assertThat(object1, equalTo(object2)));
```

? If not, I would prefer the first version, because it reads better. Are there any other considerations here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation says it all:
*Decorates another Matcher, retaining the behavior but allowing tests to be slightly more expressive.

eg. assertThat(cheese, equalTo(smelly))

vs assertThat(cheese, is(equalTo(smelly)))*

http://www.junit.org/apidocs/org/hamcrest/core/Is.html
In other words, you're on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

They are equivalent, as far as I'm aware. The "`Is`" matcher just passes through to the contained matcher. It seems it's there to add readability, and perhaps backwards compatibility.